# Regex to match credit card numbers unless they appear within a UUID

Tags: regex, credit-card

To phrase the question more generally: how can I write a regular expression that matches a pattern unless it appears somewhere within another pattern?

I have a regex (see below) that matches specific credit card numbers with or without dashes/spaces between groups of numbers.

I'd like to **prevent** a match if a credit card number appears within a UUID string (of the form "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" where X is any hex digit) starting at any position.

Negative look-aheads are effective only if the CC num starts at position 1 in the UUID, as are regular capture groups, so I'm hoping someone else has an alternate strategy.

Example regex group for Visa card numbers:

```
(4\d{3}(?:[\s_\-\n\r\.]*\d{4}){3})
```

Example string that should **not** match:

```
uuid1="836ac40c-e6ed-4026-2222-44443333f465" uuid2="46120710-5880-4000-8060-f0fadf056136"
```

Example strings that should match:

```
4026-2222-44443333
46120710-5880-4000
4111222233334444
4999-8888-7777-6666
```

Due to PCI compliance rules for handling credit card numbers, we are trying to be strict in detecting numbers in any string, unless the string is positively known to be safe (e.g. a UUID).

The regex engine being used supports look-around and backreferences, but not conditionals.

Comment: Language or tool you are using ? and you please some input that should match and a few more that shouldn't match ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use anchors or word boundaries:

```
/\b(4\d{3}(?:[\s._-]*\d{4}){3})\b/
```

Also notice that I simplified `[\s_\-\n\r\.]` to `[\s._-]`

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Ideally we're trying to be more strict than that.  Customers try all kinds of interesting things to sneak CC info into unauthorized places.

Comment: Perhaps, but your original idea is actually less strict. This solution is preferable.